# using std::thread and CUDA together

Tags: c++, multithreading, cuda

I'm looking for an quick example of using std::thread and CUDA together.  When using mutiple host thread, does it require each host thread to be assigned a certain number of GPU threads that's not overlapping with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::thread` and CUDA together.

There is no particular arrangement required for the association between threads and GPUs. You can have 1 thread manage all GPUs, one per GPU, 4 per GPU, all threads talk to all GPUs, or whatever you like. (There is no relationship whatsoever between GPU threads and host threads, assuming by GPU threads you mean GPU threads in device code. )

Libraries like [CUFFT](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#thread-safety) and [CUBLAS](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#thread-safety2) may have certain expectations about handle usage, typically that you must not share a handle between threads, and handles are inherently device-specific.

Here's a worked example demonstrating 4 threads (one per GPU) followed by one thread dispatching work to all 4 GPUs:

```
$ cat t1457.cu
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

__global__ void k(int n){
  printf("hello from thread %d\n", n);
}

void thread_func(int n){

  if (n >= 0){
    cudaSetDevice(n);
    k<<<1,1>>>(n);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();}
  else{
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetDeviceCount(&n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      cudaSetDevice(i);
      k<<<1,1>>>(-1);}
    for (int i = 0; i <n; i++){
      cudaSetDevice(i);
      cudaDeviceSynchronize();}}
}

int main(){

  int n = 0;
  cudaError_t err = cudaGetDeviceCount(&n);
  if (err != cudaSuccess) {std::cout << "error " << (int)err << std::endl; return 0;}
  std::vector<std::thread> t;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    t.push_back(std::thread(thread_func, i));
  std::cout << n << " threads started" << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    t[i].join();
  std::cout << "join finished" << std::endl;
  std::thread ta(thread_func, -1);
  ta.join();
  std::cout << "finished" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1457 t1457.cu -std=c++11
$ ./t1457
4 threads started
hello from thread 1
hello from thread 3
hello from thread 2
hello from thread 0
join finished
hello from thread -1
hello from thread -1
hello from thread -1
hello from thread -1
finished
$
```

Here's an example showing 4 threads issuing work to a single GPU:

```
$ cat t1459.cu
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

__global__ void k(int n){
  printf("hello from thread %d\n", n);
}

void thread_func(int n){

    cudaSetDevice(0);
    k<<<1,1>>>(n);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

int main(){

  const int n = 4;
  std::vector<std::thread> t;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    t.push_back(std::thread(thread_func, i));
  std::cout << n << " threads started" << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    t[i].join();
  std::cout << "join finished" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc t1459.cu -o t1459 -std=c++11
$ ./t1459
4 threads started
hello from thread 0
hello from thread 1
hello from thread 3
hello from thread 2
join finished
$
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please also include the case  of multiple threads dispatch jobs to one GPU?

Comment: all you have to do is change this: `cudaSetDevice(n);` to this: `cudaSetDevice(0);`   
 and after the `cudaGetDeviceCount` line in the main code, set `n` to the number of threads you want to run.  To learn more about about multi-GPU programming in CUDA, there are CUDA sample codes you can study, such as `simpleMultiGPU`

Comment: added an example

Comment: Thanks again. Is this essentially equivalent to nvidia MPS? if not, what's the performance difference  between the two?

Comment: No it's not the same as MPS.  This is multiple threads within a single process, MPS is to handle multiple processes.  For performance, multiple threads are preferred over multiple processes, when the same amount of work is being issued in each case.

Comment: When multiple host threads issue work to the same GPU, is this work executed serially (one thread's work after the other) by the GPU?

Comment: not necessarily.  It is a function of how and if you arrange for asynchronous concurrency, using mechanisms like CUDA streams.  The fact that work is issued from separate threads is pretty much irrelevant in the context of the CUDA runtime API.  The CUDA programming guide has a whole section on [asynchronous concurrency](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution).